# Can this operation be vectorized in Octave?

Tags: matrix, octave, vectorization

I have a matrix `A` and `B`. I want to take the sum of squares errors between them `ss = sum(sum( (A-B).^2 ))`, but I only want to do so if NEITHER matrix elements are identically zero. For now, I am going through each matrix as follows:

```
for i = 1:N
  for j = 1:M
    if( A(i,j) == 0 )
      B(i,j) = 0;
    elseif( B(i,j) == 0 )
      A(i,j) = 0;
    end
  end
end
```

and then taking the sum of squares after that. Is there a way to vectorize the comparison and reassigning of values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were just trying to achieve what the listed code is doing, but in a vectorized fashion, you can use this approach -

```
%// Create mask to set elements in both A and B to zeros
mask = A==0 | B==0

%// Set A and B to zeros at places where mask has TRUE values
A(mask) = 0
B(mask) = 0
```

If the bigger context of finding the `sum of squares errors after the listed code` could be considered, you can do so with this -

```
df = A - B;
df(A==0 | B==0) = 0;
ss_vectorized = sum(df(:).^2);
```

Or as @carandraug commented, you can use the built-in `sumsq` for the sum of squares calculation at the last step -

```
ss_vectorized = sumsq(df(:));
```

Comment: it will be even faster (and memory efficient), to use `sumsq (df(:))` instead of `sum (df(:).^2)`

Comment: @carandraug Nice, thanks! Didn't know about that built-in in octave! Edited.